# Terraform for_each in module

Tags: terraform, hashicorp-vault

I'm creating some `policies` and the `policies` are in `my_pol` directory.

```
resource "vault_policy" "rules" {
  for_each = fileset("${path.module}/my_pol", "*.hcl")
    
  name = trimsuffix(each.key, ".hcl")
  policy = file("my_pol/${each.key}")
}
```

I have several polices inside `my_pol` dir

```
    my_pol
    -> pol1.hcl
    -> pol2.hcl
```

How do I call `pol2.hcl` inside module?

```
module "my_module" {
  source             = "./dir/something"
  policy_two         = vault_rules.rules[each.value."pol2.hcl"] <- Here I want policy2.hcl
}
```

`vault_policy.rules[each.value."pol2.hcl"]` is this way correct?

Edited:

> The given value is not suitable for module.my_module.module.my_resources.var.policy_two declared at ../../variables.tf:36,1-24: string required.

Comment: If you are not going to use the same `for_each` loop when calling the module, then you need `policy_two = vault_rules.rules["pol2.hcl"]`.

Comment: "is this way correct?"- why not run the code and check?

Comment: @MarkoE When I tried the way you suggested it gives the above error

Comment: Uh, yeah, it's probably: `policy_two = vault_policy.rules["pol2.hcl"].policy`.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested code is wrong on so many levels:

- First you need to understand the correct usage of for_each: you cannot refer to an index outside of the loop used in the resource.
  In your case you are using for_each on the resource, and in the module which is an independent resource, you are still using [each.value.x]
- Second if you want to refer to pol2.hcl in the module, simply just refer to it by its name. But, if you are creating multiple instances of that module, which may have as input the list of your policies files, then you can get the list of the files names under your folder like this:

```
locals {
  all_policies = toset(fileset("${path.module}/my_pol", "*.hcl"))
}
```

Then you can iterate over this list and pass the name of the files for the module:

```
module "my_module" {
  for_each = local.policy_files

  source    = "./dir/something"
  policy    = file("${path.module}/my_pol/${each.value}")
}
```

Please note that the second option is only valid if you are attempting to create multiple instances of your module, else you can simply just pass the name of the file.